# How to perform LDAP bind given email and password in PHP?

Tags: php, ldap, ldap-query

I am working on application that uses LDAP for authentication. Currently I can authenticate users using `uid` and `password`.
I'm testing with the online LDAP test server ( http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/#comment-5882)

This is my code:

```
<?php
$ldapConn = ldap_connect('ldap.forumsys.com');

ldap_set_option($ldapConn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldapConn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

//sample path for authentication
ldap_bind($ldapConn, 'uid=riemann,dc=example,dc=com', 'password');

//example path for searching
$search = ldap_search($ldapConn, "uid=riemann,dc=example,dc=com", "(cn=*)");
$searchData = ldap_get_entries($ldapConn, $search);

print_r($searchData);
```

The code searches users and authenticates them using `uid` attribute but now I want to authenticate users given their e-mail address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first : credit goes to @Zoran Regvart.
the problem was there are only 4 parameters in `ldap_search()` function,check the `$entries['count'] > 0`

```
$ldapConn = ldap_connect('ldap.forumsys.com');
ldap_set_option($ldapConn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldapConn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
$password='password';
$mail = 'riemann@ldap.forumsys.com';
if(ldap_bind($ldapConn, 'cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com', 'password')) {

            $arr = array('dn', 1);
            $result = ldap_search($ldapConn, 'dc=example,dc=com', "(mail=$mail)", $arr);
            $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldapConn, $result);
                echo "<br><hr>";
                print_r($entries);
            if ($entries['count'] > 0) {
                if (ldap_bind($ldapConn, $entries[0]['dn'], $password)) {
                    // user with mail $mail is checked with password $password
                    echo 'user auth success';
                }else{
                    echo 'user auth failed';
                }
            }

        }
ldap_close($ldapConn);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your time, but it was better if you could edit Zoran Regvart's answer instead of re-posting.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, your LDAP server would either allow anonymous access for searching, or you would *bind* (authenticate against) the LDAP server to perform search, and the *bind again* with the *DN* of the found user and their password to check the password.

In your code your doing the later without the *bind* as the with user *DN* to check his/her password. If the LDAP server does allow anonymous search then the the first `ldap_bind` can be skipped.

In short and without proper error handling and using the online LDAP test server:

```
if(ldap_bind($ldapConn, 'cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com', 'password')) {
    // search the LDAP tree from dc=example,dc=com looking for entries with 
    // specified mail attribute, returning only the dn and limiting the search
    // to 1 result
    $result = ldap_search($ldapConn, 'dc=example,dc=com', "(mail=$mail)", array('dn'), 0, 1)
    $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldapConn, $result);
    if ($entries['count'] != 1) {
        if (ldap_bind($ldapConn, $entries[0]['dn'], $password)) {
            // user with mail $mail is checked with password $password
        }
    }
}
ldap_close($ldapConn);
```

Do **not forget to check** the given `$mail` for proper e-mail syntax, as you can suffer from security problem - LDAP injection.

Comment: it shows an error "ldap_search() expects parameter 4 to be array, string given"

Comment: Just for the record: You should not skip the first ```ldap_bind``` on anonymous bind, as that is bad practice. Just call ```ldap_bind($ldapConn)``` without the userDN and the password.